# correct column containing list of single element in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
      a_name  Season    yl
yl
4.939  cherka  2000.0  [4.939]
4.441  cherka  2001.0  [4.441]
4.320  cherka  2002.0   [4.32]
3.718  cherka  2003.0  [3.718]
4.533  cherka  2004.0  [4.533]
```

How do I convert it to:

```
      a_name  Season    yl
yl
4.939  cherka  2000.0  4.939
4.441  cherka  2001.0  4.441
4.320  cherka  2002.0  4.32
3.718  cherka  2003.0  3.718
4.533  cherka  2004.0  4.533
```

I got it by doing:

```
df.groupby(['a_name', 'Season', 'yl'])['yl'].unique().reset_index(level=[0,1])
```

Comment: `df["y1"] = df["y1"].str[0]` is all you need. No need for anything more.

Comment: If your question was answered, don't forget to vote on, and accept the one that helped the most. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding upon my comment, use `.str[0]`:

```
df

       a_name  Season       yl
yl                            
4.939  cherka  2000.0  [4.939]
4.441  cherka  2001.0  [4.441]
4.320  cherka  2002.0   [4.32]
3.718  cherka  2003.0  [3.718]
4.533  cherka  2004.0  [4.533]

df['yl'] = df['yl'].str[0]
df

       a_name  Season     yl
yl                          
4.939  cherka  2000.0  4.939
4.441  cherka  2001.0  4.441
4.320  cherka  2002.0  4.320
3.718  cherka  2003.0  3.718
4.533  cherka  2004.0  4.533
```

---

You could instead choose to create a copy using `assign` ([piRsquared's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164230/correct-column-containing-list-of-single-element-in-pandas-dataframe/47164505?noredirect=1#comment81278697_47164505)):

```
df_new = df.assign(df['yl'].str[0])

df_new

       a_name  Season     yl
yl                          
4.939  cherka  2000.0  4.939
4.441  cherka  2001.0  4.441
4.320  cherka  2002.0  4.320
3.718  cherka  2003.0  3.718
4.533  cherka  2004.0  4.533
```

Comment: Or leave the original alone `df.assign(yl=df.yl.str[0])`

Answer (score 1):

By using numpy:

`df["y1"] = np.vstack(df["y1"])`

Answer (score 1):

```
df['max']=df['max'].apply(pd.Series)
df
Out[1428]: 
   idCaseMax  idCaseMin  lineId  max  min
0          5         10       1  120 -110
1         27         23       2  150 -205
2         15         40       3  110  -80
3         11          8       4   90 -150
```

Data Input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"lineId":[1,2,3,4], "idCaseMin": [10, 23, 40, 8], "min": [-110, -205, -80, -150], "idCaseMax": [5, 27, 15, 11], "max": [[120], [150], [110], [90]]})
```